# Why the same code creates different count of database's files in macOS and Windows

Tags: python, database, directory, operating-system

I ran the same code in the different OS. The following is the code:

```
def build_database() -> Database | None:
    if not os.path.exists('accounts.db'):
        paths = ['discord.txt', 'facebook.txt', 'google.txt', 'linkedin.txt',
                 'twitter.txt', 'metamask.txt', 'proxies.txt']
        data = [content for content in read_from_files(paths)]
        parsing_data = ParsingData(*data)
        with Database('accounts', parsing_data) as db:
            db.build([ModelType.LINKEDIN, ModelType.FACEBOOK, ModelType.GOOGLE,
                      ModelType.TWITTER, ModelType.DISCORD, ModelType.METAMASK])
        return db
    else:
        return Database('accounts')


def __init__(self, name: str):
    self.__name = name
    self.__sql_db = SqliteDatabase(f'{name}.db')
    self.__is_connected = False
```

After running this code in windows, I've got this folder structure

[image]

But after running this code in macOS, I've got the following situation.

[image]

Why that work thus?

Comment: Please include the text of your code, not just a picture.

Comment: It is just a relative path. The database is being created in whichever folder you run the project in.